# Can we change the JVM Thread Scheduler?

Tags: java, synchronization, jvm

Can we change the ***Thread scheduler*** of ***JVM***. Suppose my JVM is working on ***preemptive scheduling*** of threads than can i change it to my custom thread scheduling algorithm or does JVM provide choices for scheduler.

Comment: possible duplicate of [is Java preemptive?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14545866/is-java-preemptive)

Comment: My question is to change the scheduler of JVM is possible or not. And this thread only talks that JVM provides preemptive scheduler.

Comment: Most JVMs don't do scheduling.

Comment: How is synchronisation related to your question?  Do you want to change how synchronization is handled by the scheduler?

Comment: I have a requirement i want a specific variable controlling the schedulling capability.

Comment: @nikhilgupta86 What is the reason for the need for this variable?  How much investment are you willing to put into adding it? i.e. how much would it cost you to not do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general the JVM doesn't do any scheduling. That is the task of the OS.  Linux for example has configurable scheduling options, and if you want to add a new scheduling strategy, you can change the kernel.

However, depending on why you want to do this, you can solve the problem another way such as using a custom Executor, or a Reactor style framework, or effectively disabling scheduling for a CPU and doing all the work in Java yourself. (Not a trivial topic, rarely very useful)

Comment: Hi peter, disabling scheduling and doing it all along by java coding would be a complex task which would take much coding efforts. I am looking for simple plugin or something that can help.

Comment: @nikhilgupta86 I agree, which is why I suggested using an Executor as this is the most common pattern used.

Answer (score 5):

IMHO, we dont have much control over thread scheduling. Most comtemporary JVMs delegates to native os when it comes to thread scheduling. Some solaris jvms, I heard still uses the concepts of "Green threads". That probably the best shot on what you are trying to achieve. I don't have a solaris machine so I cannot confirm though.

That boils down to two options.
1) Programmatically manipulate the priorities of threads. Threads with higher priorities will be executed first.

or,
Modify the os setting, as mentioned in this link http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24290_01/coh.371/e22838/tune_perftune.htm#CACCHIFA

Answer (score 2):

> Can we change the Thread scheduler of JVM.

No, because there isn't one to change. It's in the operating system. Any reference you may encounter to JVM thread scheduling is decades out of date at best and wrong at worst.